# wordpress loop and multiple google maps getting errors in console

Tags: wordpress, loops, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to create a slide out box with 4 localisations shown on maps. Each localisation on one map.

I have created a custom post type with custom post fields lat and lng. I'm getting the custom post fields through

```
<?php
      $args = array(
        'post_type'=> 'localisations',
        'posts_per_page' => 4,
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
      );
      query_posts($args);

            if ( have_posts() ) :
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
            $meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'real_estate_location_details', true );
          ?>
```

In my next step I'm adding to div.mapholder an ID with increment using jQuery

```
  jQuery(function($){
   var i=0;
    $('.mapholder').each(function(){
     i++;
     var newID='map'+i;
     $(this).attr('id',newID);
     $(this).val(i);
    });
  });

  <div id="map-container">
      <div class="mapholder"></div>
  </div><!-- #map-container -->
```

and at the end I'm creating the map

```
function initialize() {
          var latVariable = "<?php echo $meta['lat']; ?>";
          var lngVariable = "<?php echo $meta['lng']; ?>";
          var mapOptions = {
            center: {lat: latVariable, lng: lngVariable},
            zoom: 5
          }

          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'+i), mapOptions);
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

the console outputs some errors:

- `You have included the Google Maps JavaScript API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.` - I think its because the increment in `var map new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'+i), mapOptions);` doesn't work, but I don't know how to fix this.
- Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token new - Got this one. I was missing `=` between map and new

Could you please help me out whit this?

Comment: Could you show more code? It would be good if you can show the full file contents plus a link to a live site (if you have such)

Comment: here is the full code: https://pastebin.com/TCrhm8XV . I don't have live site ready yet.

Comment: **You have included the Google Maps JavaScript API multiple times on this page.** I think that is quite clear, is it not? Don't add your script multiple times (take it out of the loop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the issues because you are adding Google Api scripts inside of the loop - that is why they are getting loaded so many times and you have the error displayed.

It would be hard to present you with working example without being able to actually run it so please do not treat it as a final working solution but rather as a direction.

First of all you do not need this script which creates the IDs as it doesn't help in your scenario and it can be done easily while running PHP loop.

Second thing would be to change the way the callback is called on window load. By defining the function in the loop you are actually redefining it each time.

Third thing is to extract google API script outside of the loop.

Please find the code in this pastebin.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC5rsZHHAmzP_pOuHGKEUtarn2QideIyUM"></script>
<div id="real-estate-box" class="slideout">
    <div class="real-estate-box-wrapper">
        <p class="real-estate-box-title">For sale</p>
    </div>
    <div class="slideout-inner">
        <?php
            $args = array(
                'post_type'=> 'real-estete',
                'posts_per_page' => 4,
                'orderby' => 'date',
                'order' => 'DESC',
            );
            query_posts($args);

        ?>
        <div class="see-all-real-estate col-xl-12">
            <?php echo '<a href="' . get_bloginfo('url') .'/realestate">see all</a>';   ?>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <?php
                $map_id = 1;
                if ( have_posts() ) :
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                    $meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'real_estate_location_details', true );
                    ?>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {
                            var map new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-<?= $map_id ;?>'), {
                                center: {
                                    lat: "<?= $meta['lat']; ?>",
                                    lng: "<?= $meta['lng']; ?>"
                                },
                                zoom: 5
                            });
                        });
                    </script>
                    <li class="col-xl-3">
                        <a class="real-estate-title" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                            <?php the_title(); ?>
                        </a><!-- .real-estate-title -->
                        <div id="map-container">
                            <div class="mapholder" id="map-<?= $map_id ;?>"></div>
                        </div><!-- #map-container -->
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="real-estate-btn">see more</a>
                    </li><!-- .col-xl-4 -->
                    <?php
                    $map_id++;
                endwhile; ?>
        </ul>
    <?php
        else:
            echo '<p class="no-real-estete">We don\'t have any real estates for sale on the moment</p>';
        endif;
    ?>
    </div>

</div>
```

https://pastebin.com/5Tz9Ueaa

Actually I would strongly recommend going in completely other direction with your code as you will have some issues with that approach. 
Nevertheless code form pastebin should work in your case.

Comment: I'm get an error like this:`Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined` pointing to `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function()`

Comment: A quick fix for that would be to load the maps file synchronously above
    `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC5rsZHHAmzP_pOuHGKEUtarn2QideIyUM"></script>`. Please place it at the top of your code (and remove it from the botom). Obviously it is a quick fix and you rather need to use other approach as mentioned in my answer - you need to have one function initialising all of the maps which is called as a callback from google maps initialization function. I have updated the answer.

Comment: one last error left:  `You have included the Google Maps JavaScript API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.` Is there a way to load api once and use it multiple times?

Comment: Unless you are loading the script elsewhere there is no way it gets Included multiple times. Are you sure you don't have it included in any other place?

Comment: slideout.php - https://pastebin.com/N4naD1Hy , single-real-estete.php https://pastebin.com/TVLJPvNA. I moved the `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC5rsZHHAmzP_pOuHGKEUtarn2QideIyUM" async defer></script>` to footer, and the errors are gone, but the maps are not displayed

Comment: Unfortunately you did not use the code which I provided you with. There are still the same problems you had before. Please check the answer and paste the code exactly as it is in there. Please also ensure that you do not load google script anywhere else

Comment: I have added the code as you wrote, and left the maps only in slideout.php. Also moved the api key above the code. Getting this error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token new` when `var map new` – Dariusz 7 mins ago

Comment: works! added = to `var map = new`, and changed `lat: "<?= $meta['lat']; ?>",                                     lng: "<?= $meta['lng']; ?>" ` to `{lat: parseFloat('<?php echo $meta['lat']; ?>'), lng: parseFloat('<?php echo $meta['lng']; ?>')}`

Comment: Ah yes - there was missing '=' character - this is when you try to code in pastebin :) Nevertheless I am happy that it worked. Now when it works you should go further and make one callback to initialize all the maps and load API asynchronously. With each iteration your code will be cleaner and better.

Comment: I'm really thankful you found the time and patience to help me out :)

Comment: Nie ma za co ;)